# SpriteKit: insert node into chain

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

macOS 10.13, Xcode 10b3

I have a SpriteKit app where I have SKSpriteNodes arranged in a line (they are contained in an array), and I want to insert new elements into this line/array, and move previous nodes out of the way along the same line. (Think Zuma's Revenge where a chain of nodes move and you can shoot to insert new ones into the chain.)

I have tried the following:

- using physics and SKConstraint to ensure my nodes move only by the right amount. This fails under the current system because occasionally physics bodies become detached from their nodes (they get inserted with a force vector on mouse down , and collisions are calculated from physics bodies). Hijinks ensued.
  [image: detached physics bodies]
- recursively checking with atPoint whether there is a node in my target position. This works fine until you generate new nodes faster than old nodes move out of the way, at which point, the whole chain collapses. I would like not to use this because it puts me at the mercy of the update cycle; it is, however, proof that my recursive logic works.)
- recursively calculate whether a node has a near neighbour (one distance unit away), if so, asking *that* node whether it has a neighbour and moving it out of the way. This fails badly because the only way to ensure the node is running the checkNeighbour action before the shunt action is to run them as a group of SKActions, and SKActions are evaluated in a different cycle from ordinary code, so that effectively a sequence of

  let result = checkNearNeighbour(for: currentNode, at: currentNodeIndex)
    //checkNearNeighbour runs recursively and returns a value only when the whole chain is evaluated

  switch result {
    case true:
      allNodes.insert(node, at: index)

is running out of order, which means that a new node is inserted *before* the previous node finishes checking for near neighbours, in which case the newly-inserted node gets counted as a near neighbour, and the original neighbour gets shunted twice.

(All of these calculations happen inside an SKScene, so I haven't got a better place to move them. The large node is the node after which I have inserted a new node, the node on the far right has checked for neighbours twice and thus moved twice.) 
[image: double shunt]

At this point, I am out of ideas. I need a way a) insert nodes visually, and b) insert them into the underlying array. I'm not wedded to recursion (it seemed the logical solution, but it doesn't work), but I cannot see another way of achieving this right now, at least none that doesn't involve tying myself into knots.

**update**

Following [Knight0fDragon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2709645/knight0fdragon) suggestion, I have now inserted the node into the array first, and started checking whether there was another node in the same position. (This means using moveTo rather than moveBy, because moveBy is very slightly imprecise, so you'd need to round the position). This works great for single insertions, but if you insert nodes quickly, the previous nodes do not move out of the way quickly enough (the same problem as with atPoint-based recursion); thanks to SpriteKit and Cocoa being on separate cycles, there seems to be no way of triggering the next insertion only after the last node has moved into position.

My basic recursive function (minus safety features) is

```
func checkNearNeighbour(for node: SKSpriteNode, index: Int) -> Bool{

         let nextNode = allNodes[nodeIndex + 1]

    guard (nextNode.position.x == node.position.x) else {return false}

    let nextPosition = CGPoint(x: nextNode.position.x + nodeDistance, y: nextNode.position.y)

    let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: nextPosition, duration: 0.5)
    let checkNext = SKAction.run {
         self.calculateNearNeighbour(for: nextNode, index: nodeIndex + 1)
    }

    nextNode.run(SKAction.sequence([moveAction, checkNext]))
return true     
}
```

I can see no way to delay the next call to newNode (which simply inserts the node into the array and runs checkNearNeighbour) until after the final return from this function.

Comment: what do you mean physics bodies get detached from their nodes?

Comment: See the first image (you might have to blow it up a bit). This shows the outline of the physics bodies: you can see that the physics bodies of the second green and the beige node do not touch. As a result, the nodes overlap happily, even though a collision should mean the node touched is shunted sideways. Until I turned showPhysics on, I was completely baffled.

Comment: You must be doing something to cause that,  I have never seen bodies break from the anchor point before

Comment: I've used SKConstraints to ensure that my nodes only move along the x-axis and that they move a minimum distance, but that's all. This may be a beta thing, but I don't have the time to chase that problem right now, physics body  proved a distraction from what I'm trying to do.

Comment: ok, that can cause it.  SKConstraints are outside the world of the physics

Comment: Anyway, all you need is a push effect.  Recursion is the way to go but you are thinking about it all wrong.  What you do is you place your node into the array, then at that index, check the previous and next index if the nodes frames  at those indexes intersect.  Then you traverse outwards from the head and tail, pushing out nodes

Comment: Can you please turn this into an answer so I can accept it? That's an embarrassingly easy solution to 'I cannot run this before the node is inserted' (on the other hand, I've learnt more about how SpriteKit works). With the caveat that moveBy is imprecise, so checking whether positions are identical will fail by ± 0.0003 ...

Comment: if you posted some of the code I would have.  As for checking positions,  round to int since you cant have half a pixel anyway.

Comment: I'm now used moveTo, which is precise, but the problem of generating new nodes faster than the old ones move out of the way persists; I think at this point I need to queue node generation so the next one only drops when the previous one is finished moving.

Comment: all of your nodes should be moving simultaneously, and it shouldn't take more than 1/4th of a second.  As your new node goes in, the previous nodes should be pushing out.  In theory, you should be able to just apply the action to each node without needing to check collision on all of the nodes, just the incoming.  All of the balls should be moving half a ball (unless it is on an edge), so your biggest concern is properly calculating the distance on the chain, since the chain is not a straight line.  As ball goes in, go through the array and calculate where it goes next